# How to expose docker port with host in a Elastic Beanstalk Docker environment?

Tags: docker, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

**Current environment :**
I'm having an issue in my Beanstalk docker environment of exposing the expected port throughout the host. I can see my docker container has been running successfully inside the docker daemon but I cannot expose it via port 8080 on the beanstalk endpoint, but which is working with port 80.

**Issue :** I'm trying to access my EB endpoint using the same port(8080) where I'm using in dockerfile. But how can I do that?

Here is the output of docker ps

[image]

Here is my sample Dockerrun.aws.json

```
{
"AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
"Image": {
  "Name": "123456789.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/registry",
  "Update": "true"
},
"Ports": [
  {
    "ContainerPort": 8080,
    "HostPort": 8080
  }
],
"Volumes": [
  {
    "HostDirectory": "/path/to/log",
    "ContainerDirectory": "/path/to/log"
  }
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should create container with `-p 8080:80` args, as I see you did it with `-p 8080`.

Comment: My app configuration has been setup to run on port 8080, cannot exposed for port 80 in the container.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by simply adding in the environment variable on the beanstalk instance itself.

```
PORT : 8080
```